# Apache - forbidden 403 error - when different document root

Tags: apache, document-root

I've been having this issue for a while now. Never got to fixing it. Basically whenever I have a **DocumentRoot** which is not in

```
/var/www
```

I get a

```
        Forbidden

        You don't have permission to access / on this server.

        Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 80
```

My VirtualHost looks like this

```
        <VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName example.com
                DocumentRoot /home/prakash/1985/Foodini/bitbucket/foowork/views
        </VirtualHost>
```

What could the reasons be ? Should I have the files belonging to a different group or have different permissions ?

Comment: did you grant apache permissions to access your home folder? probably not...

Comment: No I have not. How could I do that ?